# Cannot find debugger path for

Tags: intellij-idea, skaffold

Has anybody experienced the following error when setting a breakpoint in IntelliJ IDEA for Go debugging using Skaffold.

"Cannot find debugger path for"

I can successfully break in other applications in the workspace, but not this particular one.

Comment: Could you describe where you see this error?  Screenshots would help, especially for your run configuration.

Comment: I went ahead and filed an issue here, with the solution. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/GO-11012

Comment: @jim by any chance did you not have Go modules configured in your initial test? The source mapping only works reliably when that is set up (including via the IDE in settings).

Comment: I have same issue using docker containers when remote debugging .